# Terraform: Passing variable from one module to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating a Terraform module for AWS VPC creation.

Here is my directory structure

```
➢  tree -L 3
.
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   ├── subnets
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   └── vpc
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       └── variables.tf
└── variables.tf

3 directories, 12 files
```

In the subnets module, I want to grab the vpc id of the vpc (sub)module.

In `modules/vpc/outputs.tf` I use:

```
output "my_vpc_id" {
  value = "${aws_vpc.my_vpc.id}"
}
```

Will this be enough for me doing the following in `modules/subnets/main.tf` ?

```
resource "aws_subnet" "env_vpc_sn" {
   ...
   vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.my_vpc.id}"
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `main.tf` (or wherever you use the subnet module) would need to pass this in from the output of the VPC module and your subnet module needs to take is a required variable.

To access a module's output you need to reference it as [`module.<MODULE NAME>.<OUTPUT NAME>`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html#accessing-child-module-outputs):

> In a parent module, outputs of child modules are available in expressions as module... For example, if a child module named web_server declared an output named instance_ip_addr, you could access that value as module.web_server.instance_ip_addr.

So your `main.tf` would look something like this:

```
module "vpc" {
  # ...
}

module "subnets" {
  vpc_id = "${module.vpc.my_vpc_id}"
  # ...
}
```

and `subnets/variables.tf` would look like this:

```
variable "vpc_id" {}
```